# iOS. Facebook. Is it possible to post a message to a friend's wall without a dialog?

Tags: ios, facebook

I would like to have a possibility to post to a friend's wall without presenting any dialog dialog or using `SLComposeViewController`. Say I press a button and a message with predefined text and image is posted automatically and no additional interface elements get involved. Is it possible either by means of `Facebook SDK` or `Social` framework? Can't find an answer anywhere.

I have also been searching for possibility to post to user's wall (not friend's) without involving a dialog but what i've found so far is some few years old answers which show usage of old versions `Facebook SDK` or just usage of `SLComposeViewController` which is not what i need.

So let's conclude: is there a possibility to post to `Facebook` friend's (which is more important for me) and user's wall automatically without involving a dialog or `SLComposeViewController` or any additional interface by means of newest `Facebook SDK` or `Social` framework?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. First implement Facebook login in your app, then you should be able to use following method,

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"feed" parameters:fbArguments HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {}];
```

Reference: [FBRequestConnection Class Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequestConnection/)

EDIT:

As far as I remember , this way you can only post to your own wall without any dialog. To post to a friend's wall a dialog must be presented because Facebook changed their policy some time ago.